# Can I used passport.js to login to Facebook from an app?

Tags: facebook, passport.js

I and a friend are developing an app and would like to use Facebook as a way of users having their own accounts without us having to ask them to store passwords or make users for security and ease of use.

Passport.js has a facebook plugin but it talks about a redirect URL so my question is: is it actually possible to just send information like email address and password to facebook for authorisation and return the users profile without actually redirecting the user to a facebook login page.

I don't see how i could redirect the user to a facebook login while inside my app and also what on earth would i put as the callback URL? Am i just trying to use passport-facebook in the wrong way?

Comment: _“is it actually possible to just send information like email address and password to facebook for authorisation”_ – no. Users are strongly discouraged from giving this information to any 3rd party app, and you are not allowed to ask users for them. Logging in with username/email and password happens on Facebook, not in your app. That’s how OAuth _works_.

Comment: Well that pretty much answers my question. If you'd like to put it as an answer ill accept it. Bonus points for explaining why you shouldn't be allowed to ask for user/pass inside the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it actually possible to just send information like email address and password to facebook for authorisation

No. Users are strongly discouraged from giving this information to any 3rd party app, and you are not allowed to ask users for them.

Login with username/email and password happens on Facebook, not in your app. You will get feedback from the login endpoint then that they logged in successfully.